# How to restart play-with-docker docker daemon?

Tags: docker

I am facing problem to restart the docker daemon inside the play-with-docker site. I edited the /etc/docker/daemon.json to add one private hosted registry, after editing I need to restart the docker daemon in order to make the changes. I don't find any service script to restart the docker daemon. What is the best way to restart docker daemon inside the play-with-docker site.

Answer (score 2):

This line will kill the original **dockerd** service and start in again an a background:

```
kill -9 `pgrep dockerd`; dockerd > /docker.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: Not a great approach. If you do this from an SSH console, it will exit again the moment that you close the console. And using SIGKILL has [its own problems](https://turnoff.us/geek/dont-sigkill/). The best approach is to do this using your system's init tools, such as systemctl. If you can't do that, the second best thing to do is sending SIGHUP, like the other answer suggests.

Comment: I liked the image you shared! The SIGHUP signal was not able to kill the dockerd service in play-with-docker. Also, you can't exit the shell.

Comment: I also checked an edge case, when you start an inner shell and run the docker from there. After exiting the shell, the dockerd was reattached to the parent shell process.

Answer (score 1):

> **How to restart docker daemon after editing /etc/docker/daemon.json file ?**

**Solution**

Find the PID of docker daemon

```
$ ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh -c cat /etc/hosts >/etc/hosts.bak &&     sed 's/^:
   11 root      0:05 dockerd
   12 root      0:01 script -q -c /bin/bash -l /dev/null
   13 root      0:00 /bin/bash -l
   27 root      0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -o PermitRootLogin=yes -o PrintMotd=no
   40 root      0:01 containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.
 6377 root      0:00 ps aux
```

The send HUP signal to the dockerd process.

```
$kill -HUP 11
```